# *Editable* Labels of UITableviewCell

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

I am asking this question as I didn't get any proper/relevant answer
(means I got the answer but not in the form that I want).
Hope anyone of you can provide me the right solution.

OK , My Question is about editable labels. 
I have one table view that contains customized cell(s) with 6 different labels in each cell.

**What I Want :**

> 1)    I want to edit the label when user touches it (Changes will be
>   saved).
>
> 2)    When some save button is pressed, I want all the values from the
>   table view to be saved in an array.

I am attaching screenshot herewith (Hope it may help you to understand my question).

[image]

**Note :**

In the above screenshot what i want is when user touches the **"Cotton" word**, It can be editable and when user touches the next word (suppose "Pallet") , change in the first word (means in "Cotton") must be saved. There will be one button called **"Save"**(not in screenshot). When user presses "Save" button , all the values of `Tableview` should be saved in some array.

It will be very helpful if you can provide me the answer with relevant code.

Comment: You can use textfield instead of label for doing this

Comment: yes, I know that but we need to create outlets for each text field (I think so !) and here text fields are generated dynamically...

Comment: no you can't create it dynamically also can use a custom tableView cell nib

Comment: Yeah, I am using Customized Table Cell, I mentioned it in my Question. My question is about how to get all the values of text fields (which are in custom cell) and save it in an array.

Comment: Try to do it the way I explained in my answer below. Should work fine even you use a nib. (make sure to set the correct class for your cells)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in this case, it is best to forget about using labels and use UITextField instead. If you implement UITextFieldDelegate's methods, they will let you know when one starts editing or finishes.

So here is what I would do. Create a subclass of UITableViewCell and make it look exactly how you want it to. Also, it should also have an NSIndexPath property, so you will always know exactly which row gets edited. (if your cells look anything like those in the screen-shots you provided, this step should be rather easy)

Also, it should implement the UITextFieldDelegate protocol and also create one that will let you know when a cell has been edited so you can save it's contents.

In your controller, you should create a temporary array that will be a copy of you data source. When a cell gets edited, you should update the info in your temporary array. On pressing save, you should save this array and make it the data source. Else, just set it to nil and ARC will take care of it.

I can't provide you with code for now, but it shouldn't be hard to code it once you understand the logic.

Comment: Thanks Andrei....I worked on your explanation and solved the issue !!!.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass `UItextField` so that they can store rowNumber and productName.
Change the UITextField appearance when user taps on it you can catch the touch event on `textFieldDidBeginEditing,`

And save your Data for a particular row in a dictionary then this dictionary could be saved in an array pointing to the rows of the table .

Comment: I got what you wanted to say, But Can you provide me some link to tutorial or some blog for this problem ?...